# Primeng Cannot find a differ supporting object 'width: 100%' when using style

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

I get the error  "Cannot find a differ supporting object 'width: 100%' " when I try to use style with p-menu or p-dropdown .

Comment: can you specify which style property are you setting on p-menu?

Comment: style="width: 40%" width property

Answer (score 42):

I had this issue when working with the p-confirmDialog, so I looked at their source to see what was going on. PrimeNG passes the value from the [style] attribute as-is to the component's [ngStyle], which takes an object. So, the solution is:

```html
<p-confirmDialog [style]="{'width': '100%'}">
  ...
</p-confirmDialog>
```

Comment: This answer returns also true for the DynamicDialog component in primeng (used at v.7.0.5).

Comment: For me it doesn't work for p-dropdown. I found the next line in Angular Docs about [style]: "When binding [style] to an object expression, the identity of the object must change for Angular to update the class list. Updating the property without changing object identity has no effect." As I understand it's connected. Not find the solution yet.

Comment: Changing [style] to [ngStyle] helps me.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/b774ab2a5811b223c49dcef55ba84bcbcfa09579

1. check primeNg version.
2. if the version is more than 8.1.1
3. update p-button style value(string) to objects.

++ [ngStyle] also works

```
      <p-button 
      label="button"
      [style]="{float: 'left'}"
      styleClass="ui-button-info" ></p-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add styles to the content of a DinamicDialog but this worked for me.

```
this.ref = this.dialogService.open(MyComponent, {
  header: 'contentStyle Header',
  width: '80%',
  height: '80%',
  contentStyle: { height: '100%' }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

That's because [style] takes a string, so you need to write `[style]="'width: 40%'"`

Comment: it gives the same result, nothing changed.